How to sub-align expressions and preserve equation numbering?
I'm using the following code
\begin{align}
    a &= \text{long expression} \\
      &= b \begin{aligned}[t]
           &+ \text{another expression} \\
           &- \text{sub-aligned expression}
           \end{aligned}
\end{align}

to produce an alignment as follows.
a = long expression
  = b + another long expression
      - sub-aligned expression

Note that I want the + and – to be aligned with each other, but the position of the + is determined automatically by where it falls in line 2, without messing anything up in line 1.
This works, except that the third line isn't numbered. Moreover, if I continue adding lines to the sub-aligned environment, none of them get numbered. How can I fix this?

Use alignat and move back the first expression. In the argument of \dobackup put the expression between = and && in the second line.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\backup}
\newcommand{\dobackup}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\backup}{$\displaystyle{#1}$}%
  \hspace{-\backup}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{alignat}{2}
    a &= &&\dobackup{b}\text{expression much longer than the rest} \\
      &= b &&+ \text{another expression} \\
      &    &&- \text{sub-aligned expression}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}


Note: Mico's answer is good (of course \rlap should be \mathrlap from mathtools), but it wouldn't center the thing if the first line is longer than the others. To the contrary, this solution is independent on the lengths.

Here's a solution that uses a single alignat{2} environment, along with a \mathrlap{\text{...}} wrapper directive to "hide" (from TeX's width calculations) what's to the right of the = symbol in the first row.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathrlap'; load 'amsmath' automatically

\begin{document} 
\begin{alignat}{2}
    a &= \mathrlap{\text{long expression}} \\
      &= b &&+ \text{another expression} \\
      &    &&- \text{sub-aligned expression}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}

